# VirtualStringTree - different formats of text in the same multiline node

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I have an instance of `TVirtualStringTree` that formats text of a node in two different ways. The implementation is based on using `toShowStaticText` in the `StringOptions` as described in the accepted answer of this question: [VirtualTreeView - different color of text in the same node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27275306/virtualtreeview-different-color-of-text-in-the-same-node)

Everything used to work fine until I've set the `MultiLine` flag for the nodes. Now the `OnPaintText` event will no longer be triggered having `TextType = ttStatic`.

The reason for this behaviour can be found in the `TCustomVirtualStringTree.DoPaintNode` method and is obviously intended:

```
// ... and afterwards the static text if not centered and the node is not multiline enabled.
if (Alignment <> taCenter) and not (vsMultiline in PaintInfo.Node.States) and (toShowStaticText in TreeOptions.FStringOptions) then
begin
  S := '';
  with PaintInfo do
    DoGetText(Node, Column, ttStatic, S);
  if Length(S) > 0 then
    PaintStaticText(PaintInfo, TextOutFlags, S);
end;
```

Nevertheless, I want to have two different text formats in the same `MultiLine` Node. How can I do that?